# USB MIDI HID with the ATmega32u4?

Tags: arduino-leonardo, firmware, atmega32u4, midi

There are existing projects that allow the Uno and other devices using the ATmega8u2 to operate as a USB MIDI HID, such as [MocoLUFA](http://morecatlab.akiba.coocan.jp/morecat_lab/MocoLUFA.html). Unfortunately, as far as I am aware, these require uploading new firmware that isn't compatible with programming via the Arduino UI.

Are there any similar projects for the ATmega32u4 (Leonardo, Micro)?

Is it possible to use an Arduino as a USB MIDI HID, while still being able to program it as normal?

Comment: Note that even with a custom boot loader and in circuit programming with a hardware programmer, you can still use the Arduino IDE to upload, and all libraries should work as normal.

Answer (score 5):

The teensy series from pjrc.com allows USB MIDI natively (full USB speed!).  It works well and does not require any firmware tomfoolery.  It can also do HID keyboard/mouse/joystick natively as well.

There's the 2.0, which is 32u4, and the 2.0++ which has more pins and memory.  If you want to step off the Atmel reservation the teensy 3.0 and 3.1 have more speed and memory; in a couple of weeks they are coming out with a Teensy LC which is a 3 with less bells and whistles for cheaper.

Comment: DrJohn you mean you don't need to use a specific bootloader to send MIDI messages? You only need to flash a sketch sending midi message and they are usable by several software like ableton etc??? thanks for your answers.